# how to hide a Folder in android programatically

Tags: android, file

I am trying to develop android application for hiding folders.

I used `file.renameTo(new File("." + file.getName()));`
In Log i'm getting folder name with prefix dot(.), But Still folder is not hidden.

On Clicking the folder in recycler view I am trying to hide the folder which is clicked.

Also If folder is already hidden I am trying to un hide it.

```
foldersHolder.folderRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file = new File(folderNames.get(position));
                if(!file.isHidden()) {
                    file.renameTo(new File("." + file.getName()));
                    Toast.makeText(context, file.getName() + " is Hidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else {
                    file.renameTo(new File(file.getName().substring(1)));
                    Toast.makeText(context, file.getName() + " is Shown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

Please help!